# Prevent TAB-Event to be executed in the quilljs editor in angular 5+ Component

Tags: javascript, angular, quill

To prevent the tab-event to be fired in my Angular 5+ component, I overrode the standard quill implementation for the tab-event with a binding as mentioned in the [documentation](https://quilljs.com/docs/modules/keyboard/)

```
const bindings = {
  // This will overwrite the default binding also named 'tab'
  tab: {
    key: 9,
    handler: function(range) {
      // Handle tab
    },
  },
};
```

As we don't want to deal with nested ordered or unordered lists, I expected the tab-event not to be triggered on empty list entries.

[image]

Does anyone knows how to modify a custom handler to prevent this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

You must define the 'modules' property on this way:

```
var quill = new Quill('#editor', {
  modules: {
    keyboard: {
      bindings: {
                indent: {
                    key: 'Tab',
                    handler() {
                        return false;
                    },
                },
                outdent: {
                    key: 'Tab',
                    shiftKey: true,
                    handler() {
                        return false;
                    },
                },
            }
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Well, there are other default handlers for tab like indent, outdent and outdent backspace. You can check this file https://github.com/quilljs/quill/blob/develop/modules/keyboard.js#L184

So you have to overwrite more :)